# Making a USB port transmit wirelessly via bluetooth

Tags: usb, bluetooth

Background:

I have an interactive board which I connect to my PC via usb. The usb connection of the board via pc is it's source of power. Any touch on the board is transmitted to the PC in the form of mouse movement.

Aim:
I want to make this wireless/via a Bluetooth.

Now,  I have NO knowledge of hardware at all.

From reading online, I would require a HC-06 Bluetooth module to transmit. After that I can pair the bluetooth from a laptop and read data from the port and move mouse.

My doubt is:

1. How to supply power?

Consider I connect a 5v battery to the Vcc of the module and somehow connect the HC-06 module to the usb of board. Will it be enough to power the board to work?

2. How to connect usb of board to HC-06 module?

Somehow connect the usb of board to the RX of the module. Or connect the usb of the board to ardunio(if that makes sense I don't know how to do this). Then connect the usb module to the ardunio.

Make provide clear detailed information due to my lack of knowledge.

Edit:
Any references links will be helpful. Using ardunio then usb shield connect to board. But to transfer data via bluetooth then

Comment: Why the downotes? Please help improve my question. This is my first question here.

Comment: Which 'interactive board' do you have?

Comment: @Bruce Abbott http://www.genee-india.com/interactive-whiteboards/genee-powerboard/

Comment: Generally speaking, you can't do this. You might be able to find an off the shelf USB wireless bridge, but that is quite uncommon.  More typically you would replace the "device" with something similar intentionally designed to operate via bluetooth (you do know you can buy bluetooth mice, right?).  Going to more difficulty, you could host this mystery USB peripheral on an embedded system sophisticated enough to talk to it, relay the data back via bluetooth, wifi, or whatever, and then patch it into the consuming software. None of the general solutions are on topic here, only detailed specifics

Comment: @ChrisStratton's answer is dead-on. USB is a unique half-duplex protocol typically carried over a single differential link; it has absolutely nothing to do with UART/TTL serial/RS-232/whatever, so typically BT serial modules are out of the question. You may be able to build a hub device that would re-packetize the USB stream to then send/receive over a bluetooth radio, but you'd run into severe performance issues (Bluetooth EDR tops out at 3 Mbps), and such a complex system would require more skill than I anticipate you have, given the generality of your question.

Comment: @JayCarlson Given I have transmit only the location of the pointer that is `(x,y)`. Two integers maybe every 0.5 secs. I don't think performance would be an issue. Can you provide more details on your solution.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Why? Connect arduino to board via usb shield. Then read data and transmit via bluetooth module. Does this make sense? I am saying reading such tutorials online elsewhere.

Comment: Crudely, but the arduino host shield is an absolutelt terrible idea.  There is much better non arduino hardware availanle, and far cheaper too.  However getting anything to work with an unspecified peripheral may be more challenging than you imagine.

Answer (score 2):

> Consider I connect a 5v battery to the Vcc of the module and somehow
>   connect the HC-06 module to the usb of board. Will it be enough to
>   power the board to work?

Yes, but only if the battery puts out *exactly* 5V. No battery chemistry is capable of this, so any 'battery' that does it must have a built-in regulator to stabilize the voltage.

> Somehow connect the usb of board to the RX of the module. Or connect
>   the usb of the board to ardunio(if that makes sense I don't know how
>   to do this). Then connect the usb module to the ardunio.

You cannot connect the Powerboard interactive display directly to the HC-06 because they use vastly different communication protocols. To talk to the Powerboard you need a USB host that emulates a Windows PC running the Powerboard USB driver. Theoretically an Arduino could do it, but without knowing the exact protocol used it will be impossible in practice.

The Powerboard has a custom USB driver that only works in Windows. However it appears to be based on a standard Silicon Labs CP210x USB-serial interface, so it *might* be possible to remove the USB interface from inside the Powerboard and access the serial data directly. This data could then be sent via an rf link to the PC, where you would feed it into the USB interface that you removed from the Powerboard. This is advanced hacking with no guarantee that it will work...

Comment: "Theoretically an Arduino could do it, but without knowing the exact protocol used it will be impossible in practice." How can I know the protocol?I want access the data in Arduino somehow.

Comment: 1. Contact the manufacturer and ask them for it. 2. Hack into it with a USB analyzer eg. http://freeusbanalyzer.com/

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Though the manufacturer was of no helpful. Can you tell more what to check in `usbanalyzer` I was able to run it on the device.